# css drop down menu on gallery appearing scattered

Tags: html, css, uinavigationbar

newbie coder here again, please have a look at my code, i watched a video online showing how to do a drop down menu, however; mine is all over the place when i hover over "Gallery". 
I followed the tutorial well so it should work, however; i reckon the issue is with my CSS, but not sure what has caused this problem. Please advise.

http://aasunm01.wdd1516.bbkweb.org/Assignment%201/LPhotography.html

Comment: There are many error in your nav, so create a jsfiddle of your header file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i do not see any drop down  html code on your site anyway there is one

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Dropdown Menu</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks very much! it was because i sort of gave up on it and reverted just to having a single one so i updated it on the server, but thanks :-)